# Mapbox Web GL JS - querySourceFeatures() function with vector tile source

Tags: opengl-es, mapbox, mapbox-gl, mapbox-gl-js

I've got a vector tileset on Mapbox that I created by uploading a geojson file comprising polygons representing particular suburbs in Victoria, Australia.  My vector tileset has three properties - suburb, state, postcode - corresponding to the feature properties in the geojson.

I can also successfully query those properties via the Mapbox web gl js library to get an accurate map.  For example I've got a map working that shows a popup when I click a highlighted polygon, and the popup correctly shows that suburb's properties (suburb, state, postcode).

Now I'd like to access those properties - for every feature in my tileset - in my web page. I basically want to dump those properties out as a list, in a div outside of the map; just listing each suburb and its properties. To this end, I'm trying to use the querySourceFeatures function of the MapBox Web GL JS library.    I'm struggling a bit.

Here's my code.  My map displays as expected.  But in the JS console I'm just getting an empty array.

Here's my code

```
var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', // container id
    style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v8', //stylesheet location
    center: [144.96, -37.81], // starting position
    zoom: 8, // starting zoom,
    hash:true
});

// Add zoom and rotation controls to the map.
map.addControl(new mapboxgl.Navigation());

map.on('load', function () {
    map.addSource('charlieSource', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://charlie.962dstid'
    });


   map.addLayer({
    "id": "charlielayer",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "charlieSource",
    "source-layer": "my-source-layer-name",
    "layout": {},
    "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#00525a",
        "fill-opacity": 0.5
    }

    });

    var myFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('charlieSource', 
        {
            sourceLayer: 'my-source-layer-name',
           // i'm confident there is data matching this filter 
            filter: ["==", "postcode", "3000"]
        }
        );

   console.log(myFeatures);


});
```

The doco is a bit light so I don't know if I'm using the querySourceFeatures function correctly.  I'm a total JS noob so apologies if its something totally simple.

In my console in Firefox I just get an array of length zero. Not sure where to go from here.

I'm using v0.18.0 of the mapbox web gl js library.

Answer (score 9):

EDIT: After adding a source, you must wait for the tiles to load before calling `queryRenderedFeatures`. This code should solve your problem:

```
var wasLoaded = false;
map.on('render', function() {
    if (!map.loaded() || wasLoaded) return;
    var myFeatures = map.querySourceFeatures('charlieSource', {
        sourceLayer: 'my-source-layer-name',
        filter: ["==", "postcode", "3000"]
    });
    console.log(myFeatures);
    wasLoaded = true;
});
```

---

Everything you've posted looks correct, Charlie. I can't pinpoint the problem without a functioning demo using your data.

Have you tried changing your filter from `["==", "postcode", "3000"]` to `["==", "postcode", 3000]`? (turning the 3000 into a number rather than a string)

Are you sure that the data for which you are searching is within the viewport? `querySourceFeatures` only works for data within the viewport.

Are you sure that your values for `source` and `sourceLayer` are correct?

Comment: Thanks Lucas.    To answer your questions. Postcode is a string, so that's not the issue.     My data is within the viewport.   source and sourceLayer are right as far as I know.  

I am getting in the console a 'Geometry exceeds allowed extent' but I get this on all my maps regardless of whether I use the querySourceFeatures function.

YOu can see my working code here - http://where-we-build.pancakeapps.com/example-04.html

Comment: I'm wondering is it something to do with the function firing before source has been loaded?  Would you have any suggestions to handle that?

Thanks.  Appreciate your help.

Comment: _querySourceFeatures only works for data within the viewport._ no : querySourceFeatures() returns all features that match the query parameters regardless of whether or not the feature is currently rendered on the map https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/query/