# Mapbox: auto fly to added source

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

How to force mapbox to fly to the source after it was added?

For Example, I add a new geojson source:

```
map.addSource('some-id', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: 'https://some.url/data.geojson',
});
```

When I try to `querySourceFeatures` right after this, it returns nothing:

```
map.querySourceFeatures('some-id')
```

How to do this in a correct way?

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37251071/mapbox-web-gl-js-querysourcefeatures-function-with-vector-tile-source

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably need to download your GeoJSON with fetch etc first then look through to find the bbox then fitBounds.